# dont draw rectangle with cv.drawrectangle?

Tags: python, opencv

I try use `cv2.rectangle` as following, but got line only

```
 labeled_img = cv2.rectangle(super_pixel_new, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `h` is non zero?

Comment: @wanger Can you add what are the values of x, y, w and h?